# __del__ is unreliable, but the object does not persist if I try and use a context manager

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager, del, resource-cleanup

I have a script that instantiates a number of child objects. When the script (and these objects) end...the objects need to do a little cleanup (especially temp file close and delete).

I keep reading how `__del__` is unreliable - however a context manage does not appear to work a the child objects will not persist. They need to hang around (to do things like file reads and writes)

An example:

WRITER.PY

```
import os

class Writer(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.open()

    def open(self):
        self.fh = open(self.filename, "w+", 0)

    def write(self, msg):
        print >>self.fh, str(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.fh.close()
        os.remove(self.filename)

    def __enter__(self):
        print "entered"
#         self.open()


    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print "__exit__"
        self.close()
```

MAIN.PY

```
def myfunc(filename):
    with WRITER.Writer(filename) as writeit:
        # do some stuff
        writeit.write("hallo")
        # do some more stuff
        writeit.write("more results")
        # even more stuff
        writeit.write("goodbye")
```

But when I run `myfunc()`, the object is garbage collected as soon as it finishes the `__init__()`. It goes straight from enter to exit and performs none of the duties after the with statement. It doesn't seem to matter if I put the open in the `__init__` or the `__enter__`.

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/GitHub/Tesera/MRAT_Refactor/bin/MAIN.py", line 13, in <module>
    myfunc("./tempfile")
  File "/shared/GitHub/Tesera/MRAT_Refactor/bin/MAIN.py", line 6, in myfunc
    writeit.write("hallo")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
entered
__exit__
```

Is there a way to use a context manager in this way, a better way to use `__del__` ...or is there a third option to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It was 2 AM my time and I couldn;t figure those tags out :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with garbage collection.  As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__), the `as` clause binds the return value of the `__enter__` method.  You aren't returning anything, so you get None.

If you want the `Writer` object to be returned, you need to do `return self` at the end of the `__enter__` method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I had been through the documentation, and did not grasp that aspect.